# How can I store input after a comma as an integer?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a program to display user input in a table and a histogram, I've got those down, but I can't figure out how to take the user input and separate it by a comma and save the first part as a string and the second as an integer. I used streams but it separates it by spaces and the string might need to have spaces in it, so that's not reliable. I also tried substrings but I need the second half to be an int. Any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string title, col1, col2, userInput, one, two;
  istringstream inSS;
  string lineString;
  string author;
  int books;
  vector<string> vecAuthors;
  vector<int> vecBooks;
  bool inputDone;

   cout<<"Enter a title for the data:"<<endl;
   getline(cin, title);
   cout<<"You entered: "<<title<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter the column 1 header:"<<endl;
   getline(cin, col1);
   cout<<"You entered: "<<col1<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter the column 2 header:"<<endl;
   getline(cin, col2);
   cout<<"You entered: "<<col2<<endl;


    while (!inputDone) {
    cout<<"Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):"<<endl;

    getline(cin, lineString);

    while (lineString.find(',') == string::npos) {
      if (lineString == "-1") {
        break;
      }
      cout << "Error: No comma in string.\n" << endl;
      cout << "Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):" << endl;
      getline(cin, lineString);
    }

    string::size_type position = lineString.find (',');
    if (position != string::npos)
    {
        while  (lineString.find (',', position+1) != string::npos) {
            if (lineString == "-1") {
              break;
          }
            cout << "Error: Too many commas in input." << endl;
            cout << "Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):" << endl;
            getline(cin, lineString);
       }
    }

    one = lineString.substr(0, lineString.find(','));
    two = lineString.substr(lineString.find(',') + 1, lineString.size() - 1);


         inSS.clear();
         inSS.str(lineString);
         inSS >> author;
         inSS >> books;

          if (inSS.fail()) {
              if (lineString == "-1") {
                break;
              }

            cerr << "Error: Comma not followed by an integer." << endl << endl;
                        cout << "Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):" << endl;
            getline(cin, lineString);

                     }



    inSS.clear();
    inSS.str(lineString);
    inSS >> author;

    if (author == "-1") {
      cout<<"Finished."<<endl;
      inputDone = true;
    }

    else {
    inSS >> books;
    author.pop_back();
    vecAuthors.push_back(author);
    vecBooks.push_back(books);

    cout << "Data string: " << author << endl;
    cout << "Data integer: " << books << endl;
    }
    }



   cout<<setw(33)<<right<<title<<endl;
   cout<<setw(20)<<left<<col1<<"|";
   cout<<setw(23)<<right<<col2<<endl;
   cout<<setfill('-')<<setw(43)<<""<<endl;
   cout<<setfill(' ');
   for(int i=0; i<vecAuthors.size(); ++i){
    cout<<setw(20)<<left<<vecAuthors[i]<<"|"<<setw(23)<<right<<vecBooks[i]<<endl;
   }
  cout<<endl;
   for(int i=0; i<vecAuthors.size(); ++i){
     cout<<setw(20)<<right<<vecAuthors[i];
     for(int k = 0; k<vecBooks[i]; ++k) {
       cout<<left<<"*";
     }
     cout<<endl;

   }





   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* as you use `inputDone` before it's initialized.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. There is so much code that is not relevant to the problem you are asking about

Answer (score 1):

because what you need is quite custom (you need comma as a separator and not space ) you can get a line and parse it as you want with the `getline` function of  [std](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) afterwards you can separate the string on the comma (the simplest way I can think off is a simple for loop but you can use std's algorithm's also) and then you can use  the `stoi` function to convert a string to an int ,all of them together:

```
std::string row{};
unsigned positionofcomma{};
std::getline(std::cin,row);
for (unsigned i=0;i<row.length();i++)
   if (row[i]==','){
      positionofcomma=i;
      break;
   }
std::string numberstring=row.substr(positionofcomma+1, row.length());
int number=std::stoi(numberstring);
```

Comment: of course this code doesn't  do a lot of extra checks it could be useful to do  (it takes as granted that the format of the input is something like : test string , 42 \n )

Comment: damn you were a little faster than me xD

Comment: @counterstriker0 but you were more correct I will upvote you and I will correct myself also about stoi , though I think you are wrong on the std::cinb instead of get line this will stop on spaces

Answer (score 1):

Code to get the first part to a string and second part to an int:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input{};
    std::cin >> input;
    int commaSlot{};
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input[i] == ',') {
            commaSlot = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::string firstPart = input.substr(0,commaSlot);
    int secondPart = std::stoi(input.substr(commaSlot+1));
    std::cout << firstPart << " " << secondPart;
}
```